# Vaadin 23 add click listener to TextField component

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

Is it possible to add ClickListener to a TextField component? I render a read-only TextField  in the Grid column component. The column has expandable details. But when I click on TextField there - nothing happens. With help of ClickListener I plan to expand Grid details programmatically.

Comment: You can also use Native Button Renderer (unless you really need a clickable read-only text field). https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/flow/#using-renderers-in-columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can add any JavaScript listener with this method:

```
textField.getElement().addEventListener("click", event -> Notification.show("click"));
```